# How to upload Xray Test Manager add-on to Jira

Tags: jira-plugin

I am using a trial version of Atlassian Jira.
I am trying to Integrate a Test Manager Plugin (Xray) to JIRA but I am Not getting jar Upload option means there is no option to choose JAR or OBR file.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to: Settings Icon --> Addons --> Manage Addons --> Upload Addon

If you fail to do so, you probably need the Administrator global permission.